# determine the position of axis in 3d space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, 3d

I added a picture here for the challenge of the day! I have a coordinate system (**Xg**, **Yg**, **Zg**) marked in blue color, and I want to determine their positions in the space (**Xf**, **Yf**, **Zf**). Those are unit vectors, so their values area always 1.

The angle `Phi` is determined by **Xg** and **Xf**. In the same way `Theta` is determined by **Zg** and **Zf**.

[image]

My first question is:

> based on the two mentioned angles, can we determine the position of each axis ?

The second question is:

> If not, what are the minimum needed arguments in order to identify  their positions?

Thanks everyone, and have a nice day :)

Comment: Are you looking for [Tait-Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait.E2.80.93Bryan_angles)?